# Is it possible to post to Facebook application Wall via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas

I have a Canvas Facebook app embedded via an iframe. I would like to include a feedback link which would encourage the user to leave a comment that would be added to the Application wall - this comment would open like a standard FB modal window. Is there anyway to post to to the Application Wall directly via JS? Everything I have found such as FB.Connect.StreamPublish(), only publishes to the users stream, I need to publish to the application stream. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not, according to [stream.publish - Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/), section on `target_id` parameter:

> Note: You cannot publish to an application profile page's Wall.